# HighCharts (highstock) - data will not display

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, json

I am experimenting with the `HighStock API` and am experiencing an issue displaying the data returned from my Server.

The javascript query is as follows:

```
var displayOHLCChart = function () {
    var $input = $(this);
    var listedId = $('[data-field="Id"]').val();
    var url = '/ListedSecurities/GetChartData/' + listedId;
    $.getJSON(url, function (data) {
        $('#ohlc-container').highcharts('StockChart', {
            rangeSelector: {
                selected: 2
            },

            title: {
                text: 'AAPL Stock Price'
            },

            series: [{
                type: 'ohlc',
                name: 'AAPL Stock Price',
                data: data,
                dataGrouping: {
                    enabled: false
                }

            }]
        });
    });
};

$("#ohlc-container").each(displayOHLCChart);
```

My call to `/ListedSecurities/GetChartData/1` returns the following `JSON`

Edit: Copy and paste left off some commas

```
[{"date":"1/07/1996","DayOpen":2.95,"DayHigh":2.97,"DayLow":2.89,"DayClose":2.89},
{"date":"2/07/1996","DayOpen":2.91,"DayHigh":2.99,"DayLow":2.91,"DayClose":2.99},
{"date":"3/07/1996","DayOpen":3.00,"DayHigh":3.00,"DayLow":2.95,"DayClose":2.97},
{"date":"4/07/1996","DayOpen":2.95,"DayHigh":2.96,"DayLow":2.90,"DayClose":2.96},
{"date":"5/07/1996","DayOpen":2.96,"DayHigh":2.98,"DayLow":2.95,"DayClose":2.96},
{"date":"8/07/1996","DayOpen":2.95,"DayHigh":3.00,"DayLow":2.93,"DayClose":2.98},
{"date":"9/07/1996","DayOpen":2.98,"DayHigh":2.98,"DayLow":2.95,"DayClose":2.96}]
```

When the page renders I see the Chart Title, zoom buttons, timeline scroller but no data.

If I look at 'data' in my java script, it says that is contains 7 objects (one for each date above), and I can drill down to see the actual elements.  If the issue is 'data' is return objects inside objects, how do I change the following LINQ query to return the correct JSON?

```
public ActionResult GetChartData(int? id)
    {
        var EODData = _unitOfWork.Repository<EODSecurityData>()
            .Query()
            .OrderBy(q => q
                .OrderBy(c => c.EODDate))
            .Filter(x => x.ListedSecurityId == id)
            .Get().ToList()
            .Select(r => new { date= r.EODDate.ToShortDateString(), r.DayOpen, r.DayHigh, r.DayLow, r.DayClose });
        return Json(EODData, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found it was related to the way my data was being passed back through the JSON object. Props to **hutchonoid** whose jsfiddle examples pointed me in the right direction.

To get the correctly formatted JSON result I needed to generate a generic object with the relevant properties and also had to modified the `DateTime` element to a Javascript `datetime` element. The code has ended up looking like this.

```
public ActionResult GetChartData(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return Json(null);
        }
        var EODData = _unitOfWork.Repository<EODSecurityData>()
            .Query()
            .OrderBy(q => q
                .OrderBy(c => c.EODDate))
            .Filter(x => x.ListedSecurityId == id)
            .Get().ToList()
            .Select(r => new { date= r.EODDate, r.DayOpen, r.DayHigh, r.DayLow, r.DayClose });

        List<object> output = new List<object>();
        foreach (var dataElement in EODData)
        {
            output.Add(new object[] { ToJsonTicks(dataElement.date), dataElement.DayOpen, dataElement.DayHigh, dataElement.DayLow, dataElement.DayClose });
        }

        return Json(output, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }

    public long ToJsonTicks(DateTime value)
    {
        return (value.ToUniversalTime().Ticks - ((new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc)).Ticks)) / 10000;
    }
```

Notice the looping through of the Entity Framework results to add each to an Object list and the conversion of the `DateTime` property with the `ToJsonTicks` method.

Comment: nice one, pleased you sorted it. :)

Comment: Thanks a lot for posting your solution. I was banging my head against the wall because of my json was not returning the proper date format. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

There is a problem with the json, the last two items in the collection are not separated by a comma.

This (line 5 & 6):

```
[{"date":"1/07/1996","DayOpen":2.95,"DayHigh":2.97,"DayLow":2.89,"DayClose":2.89},
{"date":"2/07/1996","DayOpen":2.91,"DayHigh":2.99,"DayLow":2.91,"DayClose":2.99},  
{"date":"3/07/1996","DayOpen":3.00,"DayHigh":3.00,"DayLow":2.95,"DayClose":2.97},
{"date":"4/07/1996","DayOpen":2.95,"DayHigh":2.96,"DayLow":2.90,"DayClose":2.96},
{"date":"5/07/1996","DayOpen":2.96,"DayHigh":2.98,"DayLow":2.95,"DayClose":2.96}    
{"date":"8/07/1996","DayOpen":2.95,"DayHigh":3.00,"DayLow":2.93,"DayClose":2.98}   
{"date":"9/07/1996","DayOpen":2.98,"DayHigh":2.98,"DayLow":2.95,"DayClose":2.96}]
```

Should be this:

```
[{"date":"1/07/1996","DayOpen":2.95,"DayHigh":2.97,"DayLow":2.89,"DayClose":2.89},
{"date":"2/07/1996","DayOpen":2.91,"DayHigh":2.99,"DayLow":2.91,"DayClose":2.99},  
{"date":"3/07/1996","DayOpen":3.00,"DayHigh":3.00,"DayLow":2.95,"DayClose":2.97},
{"date":"4/07/1996","DayOpen":2.95,"DayHigh":2.96,"DayLow":2.90,"DayClose":2.96},
{"date":"5/07/1996","DayOpen":2.96,"DayHigh":2.98,"DayLow":2.95,"DayClose":2.96},    
{"date":"8/07/1996","DayOpen":2.95,"DayHigh":3.00,"DayLow":2.93,"DayClose":2.98},   
{"date":"9/07/1996","DayOpen":2.98,"DayHigh":2.98,"DayLow":2.95,"DayClose":2.96}]
```

Here is a jsFiddle with the corrected data:

http://jsfiddle.net/hutchonoid/99DUu/

**Update**

I think the date has to be represented in milliseconds.

If you see the example jsFiddle here:

http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/stock/demo/basic-line/

It represents the data as follows, millisecond date and plot

```
...
/* May 2006 */
[1147651200000,67.79],
[1147737600000,64.98],
[1147824000000,65.26],
[1147910400000,63.18],
[1147996800000,64.51],
[1148256000000,63.38],
[1148342400000,63.15],
[1148428800000,63.34],
[1148515200000,64.33],
[1148601600000,63.55],
[1148947200000,61.22],
[1149033600000,59.77],
...
```

Comment: Just ran the JSON query again and the 'commas' are there, I have updated the data in my questons above

Comment: When I look at the jsfiddle link, I do not see the data points being plotted, just an empty chart with title, timeline etc, the same as my local app.

Comment: Hi, sorry I won't be on PC until tomorrow. Will take a look for you then.